# sql query for getting items not rated by both users

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Say I have the following table:

```
+------------+------+--------+
| reviewerID | item | rating |
+------------+------+--------+
|          1 |    1 |       5|
|          1 |    2 |       5|
|          1 |    3 |       5|
|          2 |    4 |       5|
|          2 |    1 |       5|
|          2 |    2 |       5|
+------------+------+--------+
```

And I want to get the items not rated by reviewer 1 but rated by reviewer 2 and vice versa into one table. The output should be something like this:

```
+------------+------+--------+
| reviewerID | item | rating |
+------------+------+--------+
|          1 |    3 |       5|
|          2 |    4 |       5|
+------------+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You could count the number of reviewers the items had (between those two reviewers) and only select those with one reviewer:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  item IN (SELECT   item
                FROM     mytable
                WHERE    reviewerID IN (1, 2)
                GROUP BY item
                HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need, to get the desired results....

```
SELECT a.* FROM Reviewer a  
JOIN (  SELECT DISTINCT item FROM Reviewer
        GROUP BY item
        HAVING count(item) < 2) b  
ON a.item = b.item
```

Hope it helps!!
Good luck!!